# Nothing happens whe I run truffle test

Tags: truffle, truffle-test

I am new to solidity. Maybe I am missing something obvious in the setup. But when I run truffle test, I get nothing, the terminal just stays there forever.

```
$ truffle test
```

... and I don't know why, and where to debug. My project looks like this:

```
ExamRegistry
  build
  contracts
    Exams.sol
    Migrations.sol
  migrations
    1_initial_migration.js
    2_deploy_contracts.js
  test
    TestExams.js
```

TestExams.js has this code:

```
const Exam = artifacts.require("Exams");

contract("Exams", accounts => {
   it("should save the exam's hash", () =>
   Exam.deployed()
       .then(instance => instance.getContractOwner.call(accounts[0]))
       .then(address => {
           assert.equal(
                 ...
           );
       })
   );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in truffle-config.js . I had commented some relevant lines. Truffle should throw something in this case.